# Redundant Value Elimination from a File in java

Tags: java, file

I have a datafile name Test_1.txt. This data file consist of 12 rows and 3 columns.The Column which is extreme left known as ID column. This Id has a redundant Ids. I want to write a Java program which removes that redundant Ids.

If one Id encounter 1st then same Id 2nd time not entertained.

My data file looklike that

```
86.0    1.2356  -0.6325
86.0    0.2356  0.86982
25.0    1.0512  0.97852
30.0    2.6581  2.25147
86.0    2.3412  1.23456
18.0    -0.2358 1.5689
90.0    3.5687  -0.8974
88.0    1.9852  -0.1478
30.0    1.2365  -0.2356
70.0    2.0789  -1.2564
87.0    9.2547  1.1120
55.0    -4.1254 1.3611
```

So as per my question ID No: 86 and 30 are redundant.

I write down a Java Code for that:

```
import Jama.Matrix;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Redundant {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    Scanner x= new Scanner(new File("D:\\Test_1.txt"));
    Matrix A=new Matrix(3,1);
    double a=0.0,b=0.0,c=0.0;
    while(x.hasNext()) {
        a = x.nextDouble();//Here it can read the ID value perfectly
        b = x.nextDouble();
        c = x.nextDouble();
        A=new Matrix(new double[][]{{a},{b},{c}});//This is Jama Matrix where I store those values. But I want to store ID 86 only one time first time it can encounter 86. Same is true for ID No:30
        A.print(9,6);
    }

 }

}
```

So what approach should take to Eliminate redundancy?

Is there any Data structure in Java which eliminate it within one line?

Thank You In advance..

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat I changed my question. Hope now it is all right for Stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using a `Set<Double>` to store the `a` values you have seen before:

```
Set<Double> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Then, in your loop:

```
a = x.nextDouble();
b = x.nextDouble();
c = x.nextDouble();
if (set.add(a)) {
    A=new Matrix(new double[][]{{a},{b},{c}});
    A.print(9,6)
}
```

This works because `set.add` only returns true when the value was not previously in the set.

---

Note that using JAMA here is pretty redundant. Just use `System.out.format`.

Comment: Thank you. I do not have any idea about Set in Java. Hope it will help me in my future work. :)